# Why does my password doesn't get encrypted when inserted VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, encryption

i have this simple md5 encryption but it doesn't seem to be working, when i check my database nothing has changed with what i typed in password textbox.

here's my code:

```
Dim strText As String = MetroTextBox6.Text
Dim bytHashedData As Byte()
Dim encoder As New UTF8Encoding()
Dim md5Hasher As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider

Using con = new MySqlConnection("server = localhost; user id = root; database = db; password = root")
Using cmd = con.CreateCommand()
con.Open()
Dim sqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO candidate(uname,pword) VALUES("@votes, @pword")

With cmd
    .CommandText = sqlQuery
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", TextBox4.Text)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@pword, MetroTextBox6.Text)

    .ExecuteNonQuery()

 bytHashedData = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(strText))

End With
MsgBox("Record Inserted")
End Using
```

Comment: ... Because you're inserting the value *before* you compute the hash, and then you don't do anything with the hash.  How do you expect the database to receive a value that you haven't created yet?  SQL is pretty well designed, but it's not prescient.

Comment: also you are not enctypting the password - you are hashing it which is one way.  you are not going to be able to decrypt it

Comment: No salt to the hash?

Comment: i don't know how to salt.

Comment: Note that: A) If you don't salt your password, you get problems such as that someone who looks at your database can tell which users have identical passwords.  B) MD5 is a poor choice for password hashing; it's too fast.  C) You shouldn't be implementing passwords yourself in the first place.  Consider using asp.net membership.  MySql has a [tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-asp-roles.html) on how to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you don't use the hash that you created for anything. Creating a hash code for a string doesn't change the string into the hash code (and even if it did, you still do it after sending the string to the database).

Calculate the hash code before the database call, and create a string representation of the hash code to put in the string:

```
bytHashedData = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(strText))
strText = Convert.ToBase64String(bytHashedData)
```

Then use the string with the hash code instead of the string from the textbox:

```
.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pword, strText)
```